# GNUmakefile cannot compile bison and flex programs

Tags: java, c, bison, flex-lexer

I am currently working on a simple compiler using flex and bison. 
folder structure :
MainFolder --> src --> Compiler which has the following files
add_inp.flex, bison.y main.c and a stack.c
Basically when I run individually they compile fine  and produce the following files
flex produce lex.yy.c and bison produces add_inp.tab.c & add_inp.tab.h the following is my GNUmake file

```
     lex.yy.c: src/dplc/add_inp.flex bison.tab.c src/dplc/bison.tab.h
           flex src/dplc/add_inp.flex   

     bison.tab.c: src/dplc/bison.y 
           bison -d -t src/dplc/bison.y

     a.exe: src/dplc/main.c lex.yy.c bison.tab.c
            gcc src/dplc/main.c


    clean: 
      rm src/dplc/bison.tab.c src/dplc/bison.tab.h src/dplc/lex.yy.c src/dplc/a.exe
```

I get this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `src/dplc/bison.y', needed by `bison.tab.c'.  Stop.
```

if I have not compiled the the flex and bison programs individually :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `src/dplc/bison.y', needed by `bison.tab.c'.  Stop.
```

I appreciate any help on this Also I need to do  Build as well for these programs to run along with the Executor written in Java can someone please give in some suggeston on how I could get that done?

Comment: Is `src/dplc/bison.y` present from the directory you are trying to run `make`?

Comment: The error message is telling you that `make` can't find `src/dplc/bison.y`, which is needed to create `bison.tab.c`

Answer (score 1):

This was how I got it to work thanks everyone for all your help.

```
  CC=gcc
  IDIR =src/dplc/
  CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)
  a.exe: src/dplc/main.c lex.yy.c bison.tab.c 
$(CC) src/dplc/main.c $(CFLAGS) -I.
    bison.tab.c: src/dplc/bison.y 
bison -d -t src/dplc/bison.y
    lex.yy.c: src/dplc/add_inp.flex bison.tab.c bison.tab.h 
flex src/dplc/add_inp.flex  

    clean: 
rm bison.tab.c bison.tab.h lex.yy.c a.exe
```

Comment: Curious--don't you want your makefile to produce an executable? You're only compiling and linking main.c for the executable. After bison and flex generate the *.c files, you need to compile and link them with your main.c to produce an executable which uses them.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling `make` about a file `src/dplc/bison.y`, but you claim that your directory structure is `MainFolder --> src --> Compiler`. Shouldn't that then be `src/Compiler/bison.y`?